# Thread sleep C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I have a question about Threads, I got a multithread TCP accplication that have connections with multiple clients. The threads have operations that take quite long. (maybe a minute or so). How should I put my Sleeps to let all Threads have the same amount of time without puting delay if its for example only one thread runing?.

```
while(CanDoSomething)
{
    DoIt();                  //Can take all from a few seconds to a few minutes
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Is this the best way to do the Sleeps? Or should I give it a longer sleep-time? Does the other threads only get 100ms or does it give them the time to start and then finnish? Becouse I have a feeling that one thread get the work done much faster then the others... Is there anything else I can do to ensure they all get it done with the same priority?

EDIT, MORE CODE:

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
        try
        {

            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                Connection c = new Connection(this.parent);
                connectionCollection.Add(c);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(c.HandleClientComm));

                threadCollection.Add(clientThread);
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
public Connection()
    {
        this.todo = new ArrayList();
        todoT = new Thread(handleToDo);
        todoT.Start();
    }

 public void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        try
        {

            TcpClient server = (TcpClient)client;

            NetworkStream ns = server.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            string input, stringData;
            online = true;
            DateTime lastTime = DateTime.Now;

            while (true && this.online)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (lastTime.AddMinutes(2) < DateTime.Now)
                        break;

                    data = new byte[1024];
                    if (ns.DataAvailable && ns.CanRead)
                    {
                        int recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (recv > 0)
                        {
                            lastTime = DateTime.Now;
                            if ((byte)data[recv - 1] == (byte)255)
                            {
                                int cnt = -1;
                                for (int i = 0; i < recv; i++)
                                {
                                    if (data[i] == (byte)254)
                                    {
                                        cnt = i;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                int nr = recv - cnt - 2;
                                byte[] tmp = new byte[nr];

                                for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
                                {
                                    tmp[i] = data[cnt + i + 1];
                                }
                                string crc = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp);
                                stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, cnt);

                                MsgStruct msgs = new MsgStruct(stringData);
                                msgs.setCrc(crc);
                                Thread.Sleep(200);

                                addTodo(msgs);
                                if (msgs.getMsg()[0] == 'T' && this.type == 1)
                                    this.parent.cStructHandler.sendAck(msgs, this.ID);
                                Console.WriteLine(todo.Count);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (parent.cStructHandler.gotMsg(this.ID))
                    {
                        MsgStruct tmpCs = parent.cStructHandler.getNextMsg(this.ID);

                        if (tmpCs.getMsg().Length != 0 && ns.CanWrite)
                        {
                            byte[] ba = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmpCs.getMsg());

                            if (tmpCs.getCrc() == "")
                            {
                                ulong tmp = CRC.calc_crc(ba, ba.Length);
                                tmpCs.setCrc(tmp.ToString("X"));
                            }

                            if (tmpCs.canSendByTimeout())
                            {
                                string crcStr = "?" + tmpCs.getCrc() + "?";
                                byte[] bb = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(crcStr);
                                crcStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb);
                                byte[] fullMsg = new byte[ba.Length + bb.Length];
                                bb[0] = 254;
                                bb[bb.Length - 1] = 255;

                                ba.CopyTo(fullMsg, 0);
                                bb.CopyTo(fullMsg, ba.Length);
                                string s = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fullMsg);

                                ns.Write(fullMsg, 0, fullMsg.Length);
                                Thread.Sleep(200);
                                if (!tmpCs.isAckNeeded())
                                    parent.cStructHandler.removeNextMsg(this.ID);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            ns.Close();
            server.Close();
            dead = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dead = true;
        }
    }



public void handleToDo()
    {
        try
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (todo.Count > 0)
                {
                     //SWITCH CASE FOR DIFFERENT MESSAGE TYPES, DOING TASKS DEPENDING ON WHAT ONES...
                     Thread.Sleep(100);
                } 
                else
                {
                    if (dead)
                    {
                        todoT.Abort();
                        todoT = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(200);
           }
      }
}
```

Please ask questions if its unclear.

/Nick

Comment: Real software doesn't Sleep(). Save it for Test and Demo. You need async I/O.

Comment: Apart from timers you can look into wait handles, async programming, notification events. Please don't use `Thread.Sleep` you are shooting yourself in a foot. Sleep is not reliable as it takes different amount of time for operation to complete in different PC and even on a single PC (depends on load for example)

Comment: Nick3 it would be easier if you told as what are you trying to achieve in general. Do you want all threads to finish at once?

Comment: I dont want them to finish in that regard, Every Client object has a Thread that recievies and sends messages and a thread that handle the Tasks that should be handled (depending on the messages)... (for example creates and answer that the msg threads sends)

Comment: No timers needed either.

Comment: Sleep() is no less reliable than a timer.  It's not needed here, neither is a timer, and the reason is nothing to do with reliablilty. Sleep() is just fine when used for an appropriate purpose, which this is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a centralized place where task producers store new tasks, and from where task consumers take tasks to process them. The problem is a bit simpler if all tasks are produced before consumers begin their work. Your working threads are task consumers. Task is usually represented with one object that contains all relevant data needed to complete the task. Working thread should not have any form of Sleep, because it is not important which thread is faster and how many tasks it completes. Threads consume tasks in a loop as long as there are tasks to be consumed. This consuming is protected by some [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

EDIT: I would propose the restructuring of code so that there is only one thread that does all the reading, in asynchronous way ([BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) or [ReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813.aspx)). The code would start reading on each socket, and wait until some socket receives data or closes. If data are received for a socket *and data are complete* then produce new task. You must buffer incomplete data and read more until data are complete. When task is produced one task consumer should eventually pick up the task, process it and send the result to corresponding socket. So socket is read from in one thread and written to in several threads. To prevent some race conditions main reader thread must not read more data for specific socket if there is outstanding incomplete task produced for it. When task is completed main thread may start reading more data.

I haven't covered all the corners, because that would produce a wall of text. Maybe there is a library that does all the communication for you, but I don't know any.

Comment: Every Client object has a Thread that recievies and sends messages and a thread that handle the messages that should be handled... Do you mean I should keep a Thread that is seperated from all the Client objects that handles the Tasks? How do I then handle the time between the message threads and the Task handling thread (or threads   in my current case)?

Answer (score 2):

Your OS has a scheduler. It's already working to try to give each thread equal time, and has a better idea of when a thread is waiting on something (and hence would just waste time given to it).

I'm not sure what your deeper problem is, but I'm sure this isn't the solution. There are **very** few cases of real code where `Sleep()` is useful (I say "real code" because there are a few other cases where it can help with investigative and test code, rather than production). Most of those very few cases are already there for us in library code anyway. None of them need to call with a value higher than `10` and few with one higher than `0`.

This isn't one of those cases.

Comment: Ok, so If I just remove ALL my sleeps the "first" thread that gets into its while-loop would not just stay there forever? I had the understanding that the other threads would wait for it to finish if not given any opertunity to "take over"....

Comment: No, modern multi-threaded systems like Windows and Linux manage the scheduling (in different ways to each other, but you need to be very low-level for the differences to matter). If this wasn't the case, then your single-threaded applications would freeze up your computer while they ran - the OS manages all threads from all applications.
Note that if you have 2 or more cores, then some threads may be running truly simultaneously too, but even with more threads than cores, they'll be given slices without your doing anything explicit.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Got some more code in the first post. How would you suggest to solve the problem?

Comment: From a quick look, I'm thinking pooling (probably the default threadpool rather than needing anything custom) so you don't end up with too many clients running at once. But since I haven't used `TcpClient` in ages, there may be an issue with that, that I don't see. I suggest a new question, mentioning TcpClient and multithreading in the title and explaining what problem you find with the code (after you've removed the sleeps). As is, the people best able to help may have already sees this as a question about `Sleep()` with three perfectly good answers that doesn't need more input.

Comment: The deeper problem is avoidable polling!  Checking to see if data is available, checking to see if a message has been queued to write.  Once the polling is done away with, there is no need for any sleep() calls.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any Sleeps and while loops like this. Even with the while loop there is no use for a Sleep in your case.

Without really knowing your requirement, I suggest you look into timers.

Comment: Timers for this?  Why?  I agree with the sleep() while-loop stuff, but there is no need for timers here at all.